# Sqlite and SQLiteManager 1.2.4 read only error?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a Linux box running Damn Small Linux with LAMPP on it. Lampp works fine except Mysql wont work as DSL is that stripped down, it doesnt work. So you have to use Sqlite. Im not very good at SQL commands so I want an SQL manager to do the work for me. I have downloaded SQLiteManager and it looks perfect for the job. But whenever I navigate to SQLiteManager it gives me this error:
 
The configuration database is read-only.
Some features of SQLiteManager can't work correctly.


How can I get it to work?
My server is running SQLite3 and I can use it via command line just fine.
Thanks!

PS:
Sorry if this is the wrong "stack" to post it on.

Answer (score 0):

```
chown -R www-data yousqlitemanagerdir
```